# How to blitz L3 missions with 2 characters?

Tags: eve-online

I was been told that one can make serious isk/h by blitzing L3 missions. It should works something like this:

1) One character is in station and taking missions

2) Second character is in ship fitted for blitzing L3 missions (Machariel with fit for warp speed + shooting small targets).

I want to test this scenario but there are some troubles. For example I can not find a way to access mission with second character only (linking mission and broadcast in fleet do not work).

Does anyone has more experience and tips with this?

Answer (score 2):

Only the character that accepted the mission is able to warp to the deadspace pocket where the mission is contained. You can have both of your characters in the same fleet and then fleet warp to the character once they are in the deadspace pocket.

That said, if you want more information on blitzing particular missions, I would check out [eve-survival.org](http://eve-survival.org/wikka.php?wakka=MissionReports). I would also recommend blitzing level 4 missions instead of level 3 missions as they have a much higher payout.

When you are blitzing missions, you are really going for high loyalty points and not so much for the isk rewards of the missions. That said there are two skills that are recommended training to increase your isk & LP payout:

- [Negotiation](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Negotiation) (5% additional pay per skill level for agent missions)
- [Security Connections](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Security_Connections) (Improves loyalty point gain by 10% per level when working for agents in the Security corporation division)

Comment: Just to note, you can undock both characters, "fleet warp" from the mission-holder, and then cancel the warp on the mission holder. Then only the "mission runner" actually ends up in the site.